# "Rights" issue When start program from another program in Windows with .Net Process.Start()

Tags: .net, windows, process, rights

i use a program to see if my application is crashed and in this case i start it again. Let's call this application B while main application it's called A.

The main problem begin when the Application A is started from B.

Seems there are "Rights" problems to execute this code :

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("myfile.bat")
                              {CreateNoWindow = true, UseShellExecute = false};
        processInfo.Verb = "runas";
        var process1 = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process1.WaitForExit();
        process1.Close();
```

I have this problem on Win Xp and 7. I tried to execute Application B with "Execute as Administrator" too without any result.

It's seems a Rights problem cause if i launch the program without Application B it works without problem.

Comment: Can you describe in better detail the rights problem? What actually goes wrong?

Comment: It happens that the program doesnt start the bat file.

Comment: Is the code above from process B or process A?  The question implies that it is from process B, but your comment to Steve's answer implies that it is from process A.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set UseShellExecute = true.

I don't know if a 'bat' files qualifies as executable.
And the docs says that only executables could be started when UseShellExecute is false.

Comment: But if i start by myself "double click" the program A it works without problem with this code.

Comment: +1.  Batch files definitely aren't executables in that sense.  @user1107078, double-clicking a file in Explorer works the same way as Process.Start with UseShellExecute set to true.